# Rails 3.2 - scope 'open' not allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

When accessing tasks#index, I get:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)


# tasks_controller.rb
@open_tasks = @company.tasks.open.incomplete.includes...

# task.rb
scope :open, lambda { 
    where("tasks.owner_id IS NULL")
}
```

By trial and error, I've isolated the problem to the `:open` query shown above. What's wrong with the code above and why am I missing an argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rename the scope, seems Rails does not work with scope `open`. http://rudygems.com/post/420138339/rails-3-doesnt-allow-open-as-a-named-scope